# verify if there exists a row of matrix M whose values belong to Tree T

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, tree

I have a problem. I need to build this function which verify if there exists a row of `M` whose values belong to BST `tree`. I have a tree class defined by:

```
class TreeNode(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.data = value
```

How can I do this?

My code:

```
def checkRowOnTree(tree, M):
    if tree is None:
        return False
    n = len(M)
    m = len(M[0])
    flag = []
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(m):
            if tree is not None:
                return(tree.data == (M[i][j])
                       and checkRowOnTree(tree.left, M)
                       and checkRowOnTree(tree.right, M))
```

Comment: How is the row defined? It looks like it's a matrix?

Comment: You don't say what's wrong with your current code, as in how is it not working? Note: The `if tree is not None:` is useless because the value of `tree` is not being changed by the code inside the loop. In other words, it will always return the value of the expression evaluated during the first iteration for element `M[0][0]`.

Comment: I resolve this promblem using a find function which search on the tree : if the matrix value are matched and return boolean. I build a matrix with boolean values and analyzing it i find the solution. Thanks for help